# How to setup missing/corrupted list forms on migrated SP Libraries on Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-form, migration

Error: *"Unable to find the default display form for list NAME."*

After some faulty migration - via Sharegate - the list forms (dispform.aspx, etc) exist under structure but are not properly mapped (nothing under Forms).
Tried:

- create new forms via SP Designer (not possible)
- create form via power apps (even stop working on classic exp.)
- edit form directly via SP Designer

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 1):

Use ShareGate to make a copy of the list again and deselect the "Customized list forms" in your configurations section of the copy options screen. This will create a duplicate list with the default SharePoint forms. You could then customize the form using content types or a third-party product like Nintex.

You could also try enabling custom scripts for the site collection using PowerShell and remigrate the original list with the "Customized list forms" option selected if you do have some custom forms that need to be migrated.